# Doubt over a term in the definition

Tags: graph-theory

I was studying a book *Handbook of Product Graphs* by *Richard Hammack*, *Wilfried  Imrich*, *Sandi Klavžar*. There is a definition of *Antipodal Graph*.

A graph $G$ is called *antipodal* if there exists a vertex $v$ to any vertex $u$ $\in$ $V(G)$ such that  $V(G) = I(u,v)$.

What does $I(u,v)$ here stands for.

What I know about the antipodal graph of a graph $G$ is that its a graph containing vertices of $G$ and those vertices are adjacent in antipodal graph whose distance equals diameter of $G$.
Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: To get *italic* letters, simply enclose the text in asterisks `*italic*`. Please use [text markup](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for basic formatting, not LaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s defined near the top of page $9$, according to the Look Inside feature at Amazon: $I(u,v)$, the *interval between* $u$ *and* $v$, is the set of vertices lying on shortest paths between $u$ and $v$, including the vertices $u$ and $v$ themselves. For example, an even cycle $C_{2n}$ is antipodal, because if $u$ is any vertex, we may take $v$ to be the diametrically opposite vertex at distance $n$ from $u$, and $I(u,v)$ will then be the whole graph: the two paths from $u$ to $v$ are both of minimum length, and every vertex of $C_{2n}$ lies on one of them.

Comment: Thank you sir. Its clear now. :-)

Comment: @monalisa: You’re welcome.